# Can't get OpenVPN to start on Ubuntu Linux 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I went through the easy-rsa setup on a server (Ubuntu Desktop) that didn't have OpenVPN on it before. I think everything is set up. However, when I try to start the service (`sudo service openvpn start`), I get "[fail]". That's it. No messages. Log file is empty (0 bytes). Where should I look for the message on why it is failing?

I am using a bridged configuration.  I think I created a tap0 adapter using `tunctl`, but not sure how to tell.

Answer (score 0):

for better debugging you need to increase verbosity put 'verb 4' into the config.

ifconfig -a tells if the tap device has been created

post your config to give use more informations